# urllib HTTPError not being caught in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to handle an HTTPError with urllib.
My settings are python3 in an anaconda virtualenv using Django 1.10.
When the code gets the try, it doesn't go into except and crashes my page with Django telling me there's an HTTP error.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

try:
  req = Request(api.lists.members.get(LIST_ID, client_email))
  response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
  print('Error code: ', e.code)
else:
  print('everything is fine')
```

TRACEBACK:

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'website']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/plfiras/vinhood/vinhood-website/website/views.py" in homepage
  52.             conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(api.lists.members.get(LIST_ID, client_email))

File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mailchimp3/entities/listmembers.py" in get
  116.         return self._mc_client._get(url=self._build_path(list_id, 'members', subscriber_hash), **queryparams)

File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mailchimp3/mailchimpclient.py" in wrapper
  25.             return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mailchimp3/mailchimpclient.py" in _get
  100.             r.raise_for_status()

File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py" in raise_for_status
  928.             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

Exception Type: HTTPError at /homepage/
Exception Value: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/7bdb42e5c9/members/d071e758df3554f0fe89679212ef95e8
```

Comment: post the traceback

Comment: @ArpitSolanki done!

Comment: tried your code and its working perfectly fine on my system

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I know. I mean it should work, because the code is correct. I don't know how come it doesn't here. did you put an invalid url? because that url I am using is invalid.

Comment: the url which is in traceback is used by me and it goes to except block without raising anythin

Comment: @ArpitSolanki so I'm imagining you can't help me at this point, damn! thanks tho.

Comment: i can try solving a error which i can see. This seems to be perfectly fine to me

Comment: The line in the traceback from `views.py` is: `conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(api.lists.members.get(LIST_ID, client_email))
`. That doesn't match the code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're catching the wrong exception. Take a  look at the last line of your traceback:

```
 File "/Users/plfiras/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py" in raise_for_status
  928.  raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

Take a look at line 31 of  [requests/models.py](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L31) and you'll see the following:

```
from .exceptions import (
HTTPError, MissingSchema, InvalidURL, ChunkedEncodingError,
ContentDecodingError, ConnectionError, StreamConsumedError)
```

As you can see the HTTPError being raised actually comes from [requests/exceptions.py](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py). Take a look at the top of the file, and you'll see:

```
from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError


class RequestException(IOError):
    """There was an ambiguous exception that occurred while handling your
    request.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize RequestException with `request` and `response` objects."""
        response = kwargs.pop('response', None)
        self.response = response
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        if (response is not None and not self.request and
                hasattr(response, 'request')):
            self.request = self.response.request
        super(RequestException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class HTTPError(RequestException):
    """An HTTP error occurred."""
```

Which reveals that HTTPError is being imported as BaseHTTPError, and the requests library has implemented it's own HTTPError which doesn't extend urlib3.HTTPError.

So to catch the error you need to import the HTTPError from the requests module, not urlib, like so:

```
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

try:
  req = Request(api.lists.members.get(LIST_ID, client_email))
  response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
  print('Error code: ', e.code)
else:
  print('everything is fine')
```

Answer (score -1):

For some reason it was not catching the HTTPError.
By replacing HTTPError with Exception, it works.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

try:
  req = Request(api.lists.members.get(LIST_ID, client_email))
  response = urlopen(req)
except Exception as e:
  print('Error code: ', e.code)
else:
  print('everything is fine')
```